# IHttpContextAccessor in .net standard referenced from .net framework

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, .net-standard

I have a 4.7 .net framework API, that references a .net standard library. Within that library there's a big ConfigHelper service class that needs IHttpContextAccessor object in constructor. I don't want to pass it through parameters to a lot of methods. How can I have httpContextAccessor object properly initialized in my library?

If I pass it inside ctor for ConfigHelper (`public ConfigHelper(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)`), I get the following error:

> An error has occurred.Resolution failed with error: No public
>   constructor is available for type
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor. For more detailed
>   information run Unity in debug mode: new
>   UnityContainer(ModeFlags.Diagnostic)Unity.ResolutionFailedException at
>   Unity.UnityContainer.<>c.<.ctor>b__73_1(BuilderContext& context) in
>   C:\projects\container\src\UnityContainer.Resolution.cs:line 380 at
>   Unity.UnityContainer.Unity.IUnityContainer.Resolve(Type type, String
>   name, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in
>   C:\projects\container\src\UnityContainer.IUnityContainer.cs:line 246
>   at Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve[T](IUnityContainer
>   container, ResolverOverride[] overrides) in
>   C:\projects\abstractions\src\Extensions\Container\UnityContainer.cs:line
>   882